# Changes entire array instead of one cell

Tags: c#, arrays, winforms

I have a 2D array of `PictureBox`, and I want in a loop to change each picturebox's location and add it to the form, but when I change one cell's property it changes every one of the other cells too.
(The constructor gets the form's object and sets it to `form` variable)

```
private Form form;
private PictureBox[,] board = new PictureBox[8, 8];
private void PrintBoard()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++)
            {
                board[i, j].Left = j * 20;
                form.Controls.Add(board[i, j]);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Where are you getting `i` from?

Comment: seems he missed one for loop

Comment: oops sorry, I did miss the loop

Comment: @NathanAbramov how do you add picture boxes to board?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think problem is in filling array of picture boxes - you are adding reference to same picture box to all cells. You should create new PictureBox for each cell:

```
for(int i = 0; i <= board.GetUpperBound(0); i++)
    for (int j = 0; j < board.GetUpperBound(1); j++)
        board[i, j] = new PictureBox(); // create new picture box for each cell
```

Comment: And by the way, I use `this` in the form as a reference of the form object, how can i get the reference without the `this`, and in another calss?

Comment: "the method has some invalid arguments"

Comment: @NathanAbramov can you post code which you have problems with?

Comment: `class a{
Game game = new Game(this);
}
`
Im creating a new instance of the `Game` object from a calss, and i cant use `this`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/22154/discussion-between-lazyberezovsky-and-nathan-abramov)